# How to hide sdcard path name?

Tags: android, file, path

Hi I created a media player. It displays the number of video thumbnails. If I click any video thumbnail, the video will play, at the same time /mnt/sdcard/funny baby.3gb file path name is also displayed at this bottom. I want to hide that. Can someone help me out here?

source code:

```
package videothumb.videothumb;

//import com.example.android.apis.R;

//import popupTest.popupTest.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
//import android.widget.ListView;
//import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.net.Uri;
//import android.view.Window;
//import android.view.WindowManager;
//import android.widget.GridView;
import android.graphics.Color;
//import android.view.MotionEvent;
//import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Shader.TileMode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.Shader.TileMode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;


public class videothumb extends Activity  
{
private final static Uri MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    private final static String _ID = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID;
    private final static String MEDIA_DATA = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
    //flag for which one is used for images selection
    private Gallery _gallery; 
    private Cursor _cursor;
    private int _columnIndex;
    private int[] _videosId;
    private Uri _contentUri;
    //private int video_column_index;
    protected Context _context;
    //PopupWindow pw = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        _context = getApplicationContext();

         setContentView(R.layout.main);

         //set GridView for gallery
         _gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.videoGrdVw);
        //set default as external/sdcard uri
        _contentUri = MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        //initialize the videos uri 
        //showToast(_contentUri.getPath());
        initVideosId();
        //set gallery adapter

        setGalleryAdapter();



        }

      private void setGalleryAdapter() {
        _gallery.setAdapter(new VideoGalleryAdapter(_context));
        _gallery.setOnItemClickListener(videogridlistener);
        }
    private void initVideosId() {
        try
        {
            //Here we set up a string array of the thumbnail ID column we want to get back
            String [] proj={_ID};
            // Now we create the cursor pointing to the external thumbnail store
            _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                    proj, // Which columns to return
                    null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                    null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                    null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
            int count= _cursor.getCount();
            System.out.println("total"+_cursor.getCount());
            // We now get the column index of the thumbnail id
            _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID);
            //initialize 
            _videosId = new int[count];
            //move position to first element
            _cursor.moveToFirst();          
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
            {           
                int id = _cursor.getInt(_columnIndex);
                //
                _videosId[i]= id;
                //
                _cursor.moveToNext();
                //
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            showToast(ex.getMessage().toString());          
        }

    }
    protected void showToast(String msg)
    {
        Toast.makeText(_context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener videogridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
            // Now we want to actually get the data location of the file
            String [] proj={MEDIA_DATA};
            // We request our cursor again
            _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                    proj, // Which columns to return
                    null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                    null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                    null);
              //System.gc();
             // video_column_index = _cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
              _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(MEDIA_DATA);

                // Lets move to the selected item in the cursor
                _cursor.moveToPosition(position);

              String filename = _cursor.getString(_columnIndex);
              Intent intent = new Intent(videothumb.this, ViewVideo.class);
              intent.putExtra("videofilename", filename);
              startActivity(intent);
              showToast(filename);
             // Toast.makeText(videothumb.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };
    private class VideoGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        int mGalleryItemBackground;
        public VideoGalleryAdapter(Context c) 
        {

            _context = c;

            TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
            mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            a.recycle();
        }
        public int getCount() 
        {
            return _videosId.length;
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) 
        {
            return position;
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ImageView imgVw= new ImageView(_context);
            try
            {
                if(convertView!=null)
                {
                    imgVw= (ImageView) convertView;
                }
                imgVw.setImageBitmap(getImage(_videosId[position]));
                imgVw.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                //imgVw.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                imgVw.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(650, 550));
                imgVw.setPadding(1,1,1,1);
                imgVw.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("StartActivity:getView()-1   : ex " + ex.getClass() +", "+ ex.getMessage());
            }
            return imgVw;
        }

        // Create the thumbnail on the fly
private Bitmap getImage(int id) {
    Bitmap thumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(),id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            System.out.println("ff"+MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(),id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null));

            return thumb;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is not the line in your code that says:

```
showToast(filename);
```

This is displaying a message with the filename